# Como esperar várias tarefas terminarem para executar a próxima linha?

Tags: c#, task

Eu tenho um `button` normal que executa três tarefas, quero que quando as tarefas fiquem rodando permaneça na mesma linha enquanto não terminar o trabalho, sem travar o programa.

Eu sei que existe um método do próprio `Task` `ContinueWith()` e `Wait()`, mas sou novo na parte de assincronia.

```
        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tarefas(); // permancer nessa linha enquanto não terminar
            MessageBox.Show("Terminado!");
        }


        private void Tarefas()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //...
            });
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //...
            });
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //...
            });
        }
```

Como faço para trabalhar com múltiplas tarefas gerenciando todas dentro de um método e por fim pegar esse método e saber se todas dentro dele terminaram?

Comment: Só por curiosidade: por que você precisa destas Task's?

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo um ARGB de cores aleatórias usando Color.FromArgb(), cada cor terá um Número. Ex: Color.FromArgb(1,2,3)

Comment: E precisa usar Task's pra isso? Por que não faz síncrono?

Comment: Para não travar o programa, eu aprendi só fazendo desta maneira usando tasks rsrs

Comment: Você diz pra não travar a UI?

Comment: Isso, a minha aplicação WF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente não tem necessidade de usar `Task` aí (ou qualquer tipo de *multithreading*).

Mas sem entrar neste mérito, acho que você procura pelo método [**`WaitAll`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {        
        Tarefas();    
        WriteLine("FIM");
    }

    static void Tarefas() {
        var t1 = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) WriteLine(i);
        });

        var t2 = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            for(int i = 10; i < 20; i++) WriteLine(i);
        });

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso385273)</sup>